# OutOfMemoryException while building java application using Maven on Hudson with ProGuard

Tags: java, proguard

I am trying to build my maven project on Hudson using ProGuard for Obfuscation. I am just executing Obfuscation goal and skipping the optimization and shirking feature of ProGuard.

This problem is only when I try to build project on Hudson however when I build the same project on my machine using eclipse or from command prompt it gets build successfully.

I tried changing `MAVEN_OPTS` and `JAVA_OPTS` option on Hudson but it doesn’t works.

Following is the exception:

> [proguard] Reading library jar
>   [/builds/repositories/builds/com/ibm/dhbcore/6.0/dhbcore-6.0.jar] 
>   [proguard] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
>   heap space  [proguard]    at
>   proguard.classfile.io.LibraryClassReader.createConstant(LibraryClassReader.java:328)
>   [proguard]    at
>   proguard.classfile.io.LibraryClassReader.visitLibraryClass(LibraryClassReader.java:99)
>   [proguard]    at
>   proguard.classfile.LibraryClass.accept(LibraryClass.java:248) 
>   [proguard]    at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:86) 
>   [proguard]    at
>   proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
>   [proguard]    at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65) 
>   [proguard]    at
>   proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)  [proguard]
>     at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53) 
>   [proguard]    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226) 
>   [proguard]    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200) 
>   [proguard]    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:178) 
>   [proguard]    at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:100) 
>   [proguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:195) 
>   [proguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:78)  [proguard]
>     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499) mojoFailed
>   com.pyx4me:proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.4(default)

Comment: >Following exception found when ProGuard execute the obfuscation >goal.

Comment: The solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387801/how-do-i-allocate-more-memory-to-proguard-with-the-proguard-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you are out of memory, either there's something very wrong with your code or (try this first) you really are out of memory. Try adding a -Xmx parameter to your build options, and give it more memory.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your help and responses. I gt the solution to the problem. There was an element  which I needed to define as part of pom in the configuration section of Proguard. this solved my issue.

```
Regards
Siddharth Shah
```

Comment: its great that you solved your problem. now try and make this answer better, read the [how-to-answer guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) to learn how. after that [accept the best answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Come on buddy, you have to add the answer also