# How do I allocate more memory to Proguard with the Proguard Maven Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I'm getting OutOfMemoryErrors when trying to use the Proguard Maven Plugin.  I have tried allocating more memory to Maven by setting the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to -Xmx2g but this doesn't make any difference.  I assume that proguard must run in a separate process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know proguard-maven-plugin has a separate configuration entry for that:

```
  <plugin>
   <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
   <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.4</version>
   ...
   <configuration>        
     <maxMemory>576m</maxMemory>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And you're right, proguard runs in a forked process.